# Custom equality comparer for Type in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, iequalitycomparer

Since `Int32` *is a* `Object`, I want this to print "True"

```
    Dictionary<Type, string> dict = new Dictionary<Type, string>(new MyComparer());
    dict[typeof(object)] = "Hello";

    Console.WriteLine(dict.ContainsKey(typeof(int))); // currently prints false :(
```

Here's the comparer I tried:

```
    public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<Type>
    {
        public bool Equals(Type x, Type y)
        {
            return y.IsAssignableFrom(x);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Type obj)
        {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

But it's not working. I'm not quite sure what to return in `GetHashCode` - I know it's wrong cause when debugging I'm not even reaching `Equals` - Any idea how to write this correctly? Thanks.

Comment: That is not a valid equality for a dictionary; equality should be commutative; it would require "b eq a" <===> "a eq b". That *does not work* here.

Comment: Thanks for your input. So it's not possible, I see, makes sense. Convert to answer if you like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That simply is not a valid comparer for a dictionary, and the result is not well-defined. Equality comparisons should be commutative, specifically `a eq b` **if and only if** `b eq a`. That does not apply in your case. Likewise, a valid hash-code implementation states that:

- if two hashes are non-equal, the two values are non-equal
- two equal values must have the same hash-code

That fails too.

Basically, that isn't going to work.

Specifically, [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132154(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Notes to Implementers**
>
> Implementations are required to ensure that if the Equals method returns **true** for two objects x and y, then the value returned by the GetHashCode method for x must equal the value returned for y.
>
> The Equals method is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. That is, it returns **true** if used to compare an object with itself; **true** for two objects x and y if it is **true** for y and x; and **true** for two objects x and z if it is **true** for x and y and also **true** for y and z.